# Doctrine2, how to return multiple of same entities when GROUP BY is used?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

When you do GROUP BY of a One-To-Many, the query will return multiple results, however, Doctrine's ObjectHydrator will still treat this as one entity and just create a collection of the One-To-Many within that object. This is by default desired effect.

I need to actually return the same entity multiple times with a different Many-To-One exactly as SQL returns the GROUP BY results.

Has anyone done this previously? I know it's a matter of writing new AbstractHydrator, but I'm sure this must have been done before or is somehow built into Doctrine?

Comment: Can you please provide some code snippets ?

Comment: and some sample data with expected results would be helpful